# foreach statement error

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code?

```
<?php
$feedID = '28241415';
$oddsArray = array();
$source = file_get_contents("https://www.bwin.com/partner/xml/query.aspx?source=events&lid=1&xpath=/ROOT/EVENTS/E[@LID=46%20and%20@RID=14%20and%20@SID=4]");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
$game = $xml->xpath("//G");

foreach ($game as $event)
{
    if ($event['DBID'] == $feedID)
        {
            foreach ($event->children() as $odds) 
                {
                    array_push($oddsArray, array('oddsID' => $odds['DBID'], 'odds' => $odds['O']));
                }
        }
}
foreach ($array as $oddsArray)
{
echo $array['odds'];
echo $array['oddsID'];
}
?>
```

The error I am receiving is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pokerint/public_html/test.php on line

Comment: Please define "doesn't work." What is it _supposed_ to do, and what _does_ it do?

Comment: @richard `It doesn't work` is usually a big sign to say, downvote my question.  Explain why it doesn't work and what you're trying to achieve -- before this gets closed.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pokerint/public_html/test.php on line 18

Comment: I am basically trying to loop through an xml file and return values, everything works fine except the last foreach statement which is in a array there should be 3 values against the same node in the xml file and I need to return these. Sorry for the lack of explanation I kind of expected that my code had an obviously fault as I havent used for each or arrays to much until now :(

Comment: foreach ($array as $oddsArray) (line 18)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing here as the question isn't quite clear but I think you need to reverse the order of your variables in your last foreach from

```
foreach ($array as $oddsArray)
{
echo $array['odds'];
echo $array['oddsID'];
}
```

To

```
foreach ($oddsArray as $array)
{
echo $array['odds'];
echo $array['oddsID'];
}
```

Comment: genious thank you so much, you have just saved me another 2 hours of work :D thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $oddsArray)
```

I think you have this backwards ...

To avoid confusion , I always use something easy to remember ...

```
foreach ($oddsArray as $key => $value) {
```

OR

```
foreach ($oddsArray as $value) {
```

even ...

then you will never get mixed up (well hopefully never :)